# Should I use my OR/M as my Unit of Work and Repository

Tags: design-patterns, orm, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I currently split out my Unit of Work and Repository objects into their own project, which accesses a different project which contains all the OR/M (nHibernate) code.

I've heard arguments that this is just an unneccessary abstraction and that I should be using my OR/M as the repository and unit of work.

What are the opinions and reasons for either doing this or not doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three advantages to split OR/M and *Unit of Work* and *Repository*

- Inversion of control and more simple configuration — both *Unit of Work* and *Repository* abstractions
  should not directly depend on *nHibernate*. Thus you'll get advantages of decoupled code, obvious way to follow SRP, and other SOLID principles. And possibility to get rid of *nHibernate* where it is not required.
- Execution speed and simplicity of unit tests — unit testing with possibility to mock/stub both *Unit of Work* and *Repository* without having *nHibernate* running in backgroud
- Design by contract — establish separate contracts for *Unit of Work* and *Repository* without mixing with *nHibernate*

ps: do not get me wrong, I count *nHibernate* one of best OR/M available for .Net, but often it's just unnecessary to have it everywhere in code.